# Cybersource API C# CapturePayment Cannot call with a TOKEN

Tags: cybersource

The module CapturePayment runs apiInstance.CapturePayment(requestObj, id); The id is obtained on the fly from SimpleAuthorizationInternet.Run().Id;

But this call needs the CC data which has now been discarded and replaced by a TOKEN.

I am not clear on what I need to pass as id parameter to Capture a payment from a Tokenized CC.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the ID is the RequestID, as documented in:
Knowledge Article Detail Page - CYBS | Cybersource Support Center

Answer (score 0):

Bust the Token into its parts. First split it by '.'s to separate the parts. You are interested in the 2nd one. It's a BASE64 encoded UTF8 JSON object. So, just convert it to bytes and then a string for your development platform.

This will provide you with a JSON string with all kinds of details about the card. It has expiration month & year, a couple of variants on the masked card number, the BIN number, the card type (for old idiot card brands that still require it to be passed), and since the masked card numbers include the last 4 digits you get that too.

Other than the full unmasked card number, what else is there?